# Нет ответа при загрузке большого фала на сервер

Tags: php, nginx, веб-сервер

Вот код, проверяющий файл на превышение допустимого размера.

```
// If uploaded file is larger than post_max_size (php.ini) setting, $_POST content will be empty.
if (empty($_POST) && !empty($action)) {
    $err->error = get_string('errorpostmaxsize', 'repository');
    die(json_encode($err));
}
```

`post_max_size = 100M`
`upload_max_filesize = 100M`

Пытаюсь загрузить файл больше 200mb. Локально все работает. Возвращает:

> {"error":"The file you tried to upload is too large for the server to
>   process."}

Проверяю на тестовом сервере. Ждет 1.5 минуты и возвращает:

> **Warning**:  POST Content-Length of 242730421 bytes exceeds
>   the limit of 104857600 bytes in **Unknown** on line **0**
>   {"error":"The file you tried to upload is too large for the server to
>   process."}

Что плохо, так как вызывает ошибку парсинга json.
А на проде (где разрешена загрузка до 300 метров, а гружу 200) сервер ждет 1.5 минуты и ничего не возражает (хром в network пишет response failed).
При загрузке файла 20мб все нормально.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: 1. На тесте выключите ворнинги. 2. На проде перед апачем какие-то другие веб-сервера, реверс прокси есть? Nginx например

Comment: @TotalPusher апача нет. Только nginx

Comment: Конфиг (и лог) nginx в студию, в частности client_max_body_size хочется узнать

Comment: @TotalPusher client_max_body_size 500M;

Comment: `set_time_limit(0);`

Comment: По таймауту может отрубаться. `fastcgi_read_timeout` например. Просто покажите весь конфиг веб-сервера. У вас же PHP-FPM? И да, покажите логи! Лог почти всегда дает ответ на вопрос.

Comment: @TotalPusher как получу доступ, то отпишу.

Comment: `Warning` в теле ответа явно сигнализирует об участии бекенда в формировани (ответа).